# how to add row in section tableviewcell in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want add row in section wise. 
 I have 4 section in my `UITableview`. in first Section there is only one row , I want to add new row at run time if user need to write extra information then other wise not increase row in section 0 . This increment code I have to give on button click. Please guide me how can I do this.

Help me on this how to increase row on section wise. I have to four button on every section for increase  one more. But if section1 have 3 row if user want add new row between row0 to row1 
for that I have to give one button icon beside of section1 and row0 if user click +button then should increase down row 0 help me on this.

Comment: hi did you find solution to this problem? i am also facing same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can take BOOL value in .h file

for example

**Class1.h**

```
BOOL checkValue;
```

**Class1.m**

In viewDidLoad

```
checkValue=NO;
```

in no of rows in section delegate method

```
if(section==0) {
    if(checkValue) {
        return 2;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

You just write the code for 2 rows in section 0 in cell for row at index path method
in Button Action You just write the code like :

```
-(IBAction)btnAct {
    checkValue=YES;
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Note: This code helps you increase only one row

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

this is your answer.

**Update**

```
-(IBAction)plusSignTapped {
       [myTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
}
```

You should also don't forget to increase the return value for

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Comment: -(IBAction)plusSignTapped
{
 rowForSectionOne++;
 //str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",rowForSectionOne];
// NSLog(@"*********:%d",str);
 [self.mytableview reloadData];
 
}                                                                                                         - (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
{
 if ([indexPaths row] == 0 && [indexPaths section] == 0)
 {
  rowForSectionOne++;
 }
}